# How to make sure two thread access same resource and make them Thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

I'm new to multithreading and I have some basic question for which I could not get answers for. Let's say I have a class named BankTransaction and I want to handle multithreading case in there.

### CASE 1 (Application based singleton)

```
@Singleton (Application based singleton)
class BankTransaction {
    synchronized void doSomeTransaction() {
        // write operation
    }
}
```

### Case 2 (Request based singleton)

```
@Singleton (Request based singleton)
class BankTransaction{
    synchronized void doSomeTransaction() {
        // write operation
    }
}
```

### Questions

Please bear with me and explain me in layman terms as I need to get things cleared.

1. In Case 1, if 1000 users are making use of the same instance (as it is application based singleton) of class BankTransaction and use the method doSomeTransaction(), the requests for each of the 1000 users be slow? because it is synchronized and will work Thread-safe. So, it is bad approach right. Is my understanding correct?
2. In Case 2, if the same 1000 users are making use of doSomeTransaction() method of class BankTransaction, each will get their own instances of class BankTransaction and it will be never slow for any one of them. But how do I handle race condition when say for example out of those 1000 users, 2 of them are closely related (husband and wife) and are accessing same bank account and doing doSomeOperation() method at the same time. How do I handle this? because both of them again have 2 different instances of class BankTransaction and data inconsistency would occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. Your understanding is correct. You should make a method synchronized if somehow you don't want to allow multiple users to change the state of an object. The example could be application level configuration object.
2. Now, there are many solutions for this. Easiest could be to defer this problem to some ORM solution which can further use record level lock technique or anything.  However, if you want to handle this manually, easiest way to do this is to maintain a column in db. Now, every time you modify the record, you should increment that value. And before committing your record, you should check if the value is same as that of the record you fetched from db. If its same, then you can be sure that no one has modified it since you started your transaction. However, if the value is not same, you can thow an error to the user saying record has been modified by other user.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the first Case the 1000 users (or their threads) would wait a long time because only one can get access to the method at a time. All others will have to wait for the lock to get the access to this method. So, yes, it would be slow.
2. If every user has his own instance of the class BankTransaction it will NOT be slow, because the lock on the method is for an object (the lock object would be "this" in this implementation). So the users (or their threads) only wait if there is another user that wants to use the same method of exactly the same object (what should not be the case if every user has his own instance).

Comment: But how do I handle race condition when say for example out of those 1000 users, 2 of them are closely related (husband and wife) and are accessing same bank account and doing doSomeOperation() method at the same time. How do I handle this? because both of them again have 2 different instances of class BankTransaction and data inconsistency would occur?

Comment: If two users try to access the same data (e.g. the same variable that holds the amount of money on the bank account) I think you simply can't call the methods at the same time. The method calls would be executed one after another.
If the two users (husband and wife) have different BankTransaction objects they will execute the method on different objects and the data will be inconsistent.
But if there are only two users for one account the waiting period (because of the synchronized block) will not be very long, so you could use the same instance for both of them.

Comment: Tobias, How do you return same instance for both of them? Is there any framework that handles it? Or should we keep track of it using custom data structures?

Comment: I think that depends on how secure you want it to be. If you need security and authentification it could be a bit harder. If you just want the same instance for everyone who has the same name or knows the name or number of the bank account you can use a map:
Map<String, BankTransaction> mappings = new HashMap<>();

So you can get the right BankTransaction using:
BankTransaction shared = mappings.get("YourBankAccountName");

Then everyone who has the correct name can use the same BankTransaction object.